# Is below set is open In $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with usual topology. Let $S =\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ . Then the set $S$ is ?

1) open but not closed
2) both open and closed
3) neither open nor closed
4) closed but not open ??

**My attempt**: I can able to see $S$ is closed set in $\mathbb{R^2}$. Since $\mathbb{R^2}-S$ is union of vertical strips which are open and hence $\mathbb{R^2}-S$ is open, so that $S$ is closed. But in key, it was given that it is open too, but I am not able to see, how it is open in $\mathbb{R^2}$. Please help me...

Comment: The set $S$ is not open in the usual topology. Your answer key is wrong. (Proof: Look at $(0,0) \in S$. There's no open ball around $(0,0)$ that's also contained in $S$.)

Comment: Don't believe the key. Ignoring seen that, what would you say?

Comment: @JohnHughes sir, thanks for your reply, get it :-)

Comment: @Berci sir, yes I can see the, if we take any integer point of $S$, then open ball around it, does not contained in $S$, hence not open. But due to wrong key, I get confused!! :-(

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2114956/consider-mathbbr2-with-usual-topology-let-s-x-y-in-r2-x-text).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with usual topology. let $S =\{(x,y) \in R^2 : x~~ \text{is an integer}\}$ . Then the set S is?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2114956/consider-mathbbr2-with-usual-topology-let-s-x-y-in-r2-x-text)

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi: You can write yourself an answer based on John's comment and accept it, since you got it. =)